# My display suddenly has overscan out of the blue?

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics

I have Intel HD 4000 and up until I ran the game Strider, I have perfectly aligned display. Now I have overscan and my Windows desktop goes through the edges of the display. I can change it back to "normal" from the Intel Graphics Properties by scaling it down the custom way but I want to fix the root of the problem. I didn't have this issue prior and I want to "reset" it back. What can I do?

---

**Edit**: Further testing showed that the case seem to be isolated to the HDMI port at the back of the display. When I moved the HDMI cable to the port on the side, it went back to normal. The BIOS screen is affected by the overscan too on the back port.

Comment: overscan mostly happens by your graphics drivers. it seems like you 'resetted' it by changing the intel driver settings?

Comment: I checked the BIOS and the overscan is also there so I don't think it's the driver at this point.

Comment: Additional note, when I moved the HDMI cable to the other port on my monitor, it went back to normal. So somehow I managed to screw up the scaling on the first HDMI port. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was idiosyncratic to the users setup and was resolved years ago. No value to future users of the site.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, for some reason, my monitor's scale settings got reset to "Full" when it should be in the PC mode.